# Cannot use specific version of bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian

I'm on Debian 9 and I'm trying to use the 1.16.3 version of bundler on a ruby on rails site. However for some reason the system insists on using the older version 1.13.6 both by default and when I explicitly specify it:

[image]

To resolve this I tried completely uninstalling the 1.13.6 version:

[image]

Now I'm starting to feel like I'm taking crazy pills. Is it physically possible to use the 1.16.3 version?

**Edit in reply to matthewd:** which -a bundler finds two hits:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundler
/usr/bin/bundler
```

If run with bundler -v both report to be version 1.13.6

**Edit in reply to Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna:** There is no .rvm directory in /home/manos/. Could this be somewhere else?

Comment: Try `which -a bundler` -- it sounds like you might be hitting a dpkg-installed binary instead of a rubygems-managed one

Comment: Can you try doing this - `gem uninstall -i /home/{your_user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.x.x bundler -x` and then install using `gem install bundler -v 1.16.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth I ended up uninstalling ruby and rails that were previously installed via apt. I then reinstalled ruby via apt and instead of getting rails via apt I got it with

```
gem install rails
```

Bundler is now at 1.16.3.

A disclaimer though... since this whole thing has been a side issue while I was dealing with other rails problems, I've also done a bunch of other reinstalling so there's a chance something there affected the bundler. So there's that.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is pain in the a**

You can solve this by executing these set of commands. Keep in consideration your ruby version also.

```
before_install:
- rvm implode --force
- \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s 1.27.0
- rvm reload
- rvm install 2.2.3
- gem uninstall -i /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3 bundler -x
- gem install bundler -v 1.16.3
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but rvm only ended up complicating things for me.